# Creation pyodbc cursor to multiple databases

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am processing events stored in MS-Access databases using pyodbc.
Each month is a seperate file / database and I would like to process events from multiple months.

Is it possible to create a cursor to a view containing multiple months i.e. database connections?

Edit 1: And without having to write a new database? (Something like UNION VIEW maybe?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to make multiple connections and cursors, but you should be able to process the data.

Let's say the files are stored as `month_1.mdb`, `month_2.mdb`, etc. in `C:\access`.

```
# Set up each connection, must have a way to access each file's name
connect_string = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\access\\month_{}.mdb;"
# Assuming that you'll get the same data from each database
sql = "SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM table"
# Connect to each file
connections = [pyodbc.connect(connect_string.format(n)) for n in range(1, 12 + 1)]
# Create a cursor for each file
cursors = [conn.cursor() for conn in connections]
# Query each file and save the data
data = []
for cur in cursors:
  cur.execute(sql)
  data.extend(cur.fetchall())
```

OK, so now you have all the data. You can create an in-memory database with the `sqlite3` module and then do queries against it.

```
import sqlite3
# Create your temporary database
connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = connection.cursor()
# Set up a place to hold the data fetched previously
_ = cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t(x INTEGER, y INTEGER)")
# Dump all the data into the database
for column_1, column_2 in data:
  _ = cursor.execute("INSERT INTO t VALUES (?, ?)", [column_1, column_2])
# Now you can run queries against the new view of your data
sql = "SELECT t.column_1, t.count(*) FROM t GROUP BY t.column_1"
```

Comment: This executes the SQL seperately for each. Which means that I have to postprocess the data (e.g. when using GROUP BY the resulting data still has duplicate entries). What I would like is a cursor which lets me execute an SQL query over all databases as if they were one.

Comment: You could get all the data as shown above and then dump the results into a new database, then query that separately. Python includes the [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sqlite3.html) module, which makes this a snap.

Comment: I edited the answer to include an example of how to do this. You can avoid creating a new Access database and use a throwaway sqlite database.